Blocking caused by OLEDB in SQL Server
I created several views on SQL Server whose task was to retrieve data from an Excel file (1 view from a different data source/Excel file) whose purpose was to synchronize the data in the database with the data in Excel and later synchronize this data which will be displayed in the weekly report, but sometimes the process is locked by a wait type "OLEDB".
I can't find the root use, but my biggest problem is that I can't kill the process using:
KILL <spid>

Then, I also tried using:
KILL <spid> WITH STATUSONLY

I got:
"SPID <spid>: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds."

The process is still running with the query status running with a long execution time and this makes me dizzy when I read an article in Microsoft in the Detailed blocking scenarios section which states:

An actively running query has acquired a lock, and the lock is not released (affected by transaction level isolation), so another session will wait until they are released.

And that's right, all the queries I do on the database are deadlocked. I've tried the Resolution they embedded and it still doesn't work.

Be aware that using the ACE driver in a server environment (non UI) is not supported. It works sort of, but lots of issues, so you won't get any help from Microsoft. Use a client tool such as Import/Export Wizard instead.

Just a nitpick but a deadlock in sql server is resolved by killing some process, so you're probably just having a long block. I'm guessing either someone have the excel file opened or some other COM juju is being stuck somewhere while working with excel file. You should restructure your processing, the best would be to avoid excel altogether, but if you must, use some SSIS task or python / powershell / whatever-language-youre-comfortable-with script to read data into sql server and back, thus avoiding the blockage
